# Limits Involving Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, infinity

In calculus, when we encounter limits of the form “A/0” where A is non-zero, this is not an indeterminate form and by observing the functions, most of the time each side blows up to $+ \infty$ or $-\infty$

Is this always the case, ie. if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = k$, $k$ non-zero, and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$ is $\lim_{x\to a} \lvert \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\rvert = \infty$, where we take absolute value because we only care about the magnitude?

If so, how do we prove that limits in that form always eventually grow without bound and not just purely oscillating in some bounded amount? If not, what are counterexamples, and under what conditions where limits of that form have its magnitude blow up to infinity?

Comment: The absolute value of that ratio can't oscillate since for $x$ large you know the numerator is near $k$ and the denominator is near $0$. So the fraction is guaranteed large.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a,$ and $f(a) = k$ and $g(a) = 0,$ then in a neighborhood of a, $k-\epsilon < f(a+\delta) < k+\epsilon$ while $|g(a+\delta)|<\epsilon.$

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Ohh I see... What if g(x) takes on the value of 0 infinitely often as x approaches a (g oscillates toward 0) , f/g will simply be undefined in those points, will the limit still be defined?

Comment: The ratio will be undefined when the denominator is $0$. But when it's not $0$ it will be near $0$ so the fraction will grow without bound as $x$ approaches $0$ through the points where the fraction is defined. If your definition of limit allows for gaps in the domain near $0$ then the limit will be infinity.

Comment: @JimAllysonNevado Good question in your comment. Different sources treat this differently: some allow limits to exist when the function is not defined on a whole neighborhood of $x=a$, while others require the function to be defined on a whole (punctured) neighborhood of $x=a$ for the limit to exist. I prefer the second interpretation for first courses in calculus.

Comment: @user317176 - continuity is not necessary. Only $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = k$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 0$ is needed.

Comment: Consider the case $$f(x) = 1, g(x) = \begin{cases}x\sin\frac1x&x\ne0,\sin\frac1x \ne 0\\x&x\ne0,\sin\frac1x =0\\1&x = 0\end{cases}$$ Then the domain is all of $\Bbb R$. yet you have the function approaching both $\pm \infty$ infinitely many times as $x\to 0$. Yet still, the absolute value of the limit goes to $\to \infty$, because while it approaches $\infty$ infinitely many times, the *lower bounds* on the function go to $\infty$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, following the first comment, I was able to make a rigorous proof using epsilon-delta style proof. But what bothered me is the seemingly counterexample to my “proof” when we take g(x) = 0, And obviously limits will never exist let alone blow up to infinity, because f/g is undefined everywhere and so I also wondered about the effects of making the f/g undefined infinitely often near x=a to the limit. It turns out it boils down to the subtlety in definitions and somehow I assumed that f/g is always defined near a in my proof.